# Outputting variables to text file

Tags: c++

I have created a file that runs Eulers method and I don't know how to get the variables calculated to appear in a text file. I want every iteration of y and x to be shown. I am sorry but I am very inexperienced with c++ and cant see why this won't work. If someone can help it will be most appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double h = (1.0 / 100.0);
    double y = 0;
    double x = 0;


    for (x = 0; x <= 1; x = x + h)
    {
        y = y + h*(x*exp(3 * x) - 2 * y);


        ofstream demoFile;
        demoFile.open("texttexttext.txt");
        if (!demoFile) return 1;
        demoFile << y << ' ' << x << endl;


    }


    demoFile.close();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Is the file not created?

Comment: Are you running this program in your drive which contains the OS? Sometimes creating files and folders at some locations might require special permission, and so the program won't be able to create the file

Answer (score 4):

keep these lines outside of your loop.

```
ofstream demoFile;
demoFile.open("texttexttext.txt");
if (!demoFile) return 1;
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that but then I only get the final values x and y outputted. I want every iteration....

Comment: It gives me expected output @George

Comment: Are you sure you have the print statement inside the loop and not after it?

Comment: This answer is correct. put the code that fails in the question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are having is you are opening the file every iteration which is causing you to overwrite the file every iteration.  If you move the file opening out of the for loop you will get the correct text file.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double h = (1.0 / 100.0);
    double y = 0;
    double x = 0;
    ofstream demoFile("texttexttext.txt"); // no need to call open just open with the constructor
    if (!demoFile) return 1;

    for (x = 0; x <= 1; x = x + h)
    {
        y = y + h*(x*exp(3 * x) - 2 * y);

        demoFile << y << ' ' << x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```